# Boost ASIO Asynchronous TCP daytime server example fails with "Connection reset by peer" on responses over 65536 bytes

Tags: c++, sockets, boost, tcp, asio

I took the example code from [boost website](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_79_0/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial/tutdaytime3.html) and modified it to return responses 100k+ bytes long.

```
message_ = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nContent-Length: 100000\r\n\r\n";
message_ += std::string(100000, 'X');
```

When run and I `curl` the endpoint, it sometimes returns the correct response but more often it fails after received exactly 65536 bytes with `curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer`.

I've tried adding different socket/acceptor flags, closing the socket, `shutdown` and writing response in small chunks, but all failed to resolve this. I've also checked that the socket is open on the application side after writing the response, and it is. Application does not report any error code and indicates the entire message has been written (checked the `bytes_transferred`). Any advice on what I'm doing wrong here?

Full listing below

```
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/bind/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/enable_shared_from_this.hpp>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

using boost::asio::ip::tcp;

class tcp_connection
  : public boost::enable_shared_from_this<tcp_connection>
{
public:
  typedef boost::shared_ptr<tcp_connection> pointer;

  static pointer create(boost::asio::io_context& io_context)
  {
    return pointer(new tcp_connection(io_context));
  }

  tcp::socket& socket()
  {
    return socket_;
  }

  void start()
  {
    message_ = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nContent-Length: 100000\r\n\r\n";
    message_ += std::string(100000, 'X');

    boost::asio::async_write(socket_, boost::asio::buffer(message_),
        boost::bind(&tcp_connection::handle_write, shared_from_this(),
          boost::asio::placeholders::error,
          boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
  }

private:
  tcp_connection(boost::asio::io_context& io_context)
    : socket_(io_context)
  {
  }

  void handle_write(const boost::system::error_code& /*error*/,
      size_t /*bytes_transferred*/)
  {
  }

  tcp::socket socket_;
  std::string message_;
};

class tcp_server
{
public:
  tcp_server(boost::asio::io_context& io_context)
    : io_context_(io_context),
      acceptor_(io_context, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), 9000))
  {
    start_accept();
  }

private:
  void start_accept()
  {
    tcp_connection::pointer new_connection =
      tcp_connection::create(io_context_);

    acceptor_.async_accept(new_connection->socket(),
        boost::bind(&tcp_server::handle_accept, this, new_connection,
          boost::asio::placeholders::error));
  }

  void handle_accept(tcp_connection::pointer new_connection,
      const boost::system::error_code& error)
  {
    if (!error)
    {
      new_connection->start();
    }

    start_accept();
  }

  boost::asio::io_context& io_context_;
  tcp::acceptor acceptor_;
};

int main()
{
  try
  {
    boost::asio::io_context io_context;
    tcp_server server(io_context);
    io_context.run();
  }
  catch (std::exception& e)
  {
    std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What number is bytes_transferred equal to?

Comment: It was 100000 + the header length, indicating total success.

Comment: maybe check in wireshark what is actually sent

Answer (score 0):

The reason this was not working is because the boost example is not prepared to serve HTTP traffic properly. I've found the answer to this from another SO question [boost::asio fails to close TCP connection cleanly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3170319/boostasio-fails-to-close-tcp-connection-cleanly)

In essence it's necessary to read the HTTP request (even if it's not useful) before attempting to send a response. Why the example code from my question works for responses up to 65536 bytes remains a mystery to me, but it's probably because of `curl` implementation specifics.

So my `tcp_connection::start()` should look like the following:

```
void start() {
    boost::asio::async_read_until(socket_, input_buffer_, "\r\n\r\n",
        boost::bind(&tcp_connection::handle_read,
                    shared_from_this(),
                    boost::asio::placeholders::error);
}
```

With `input_buffer_` being `boost::asio::streambuf` instance defined in `tcp_connection`. Only after that I can call `boost::asio::async_write` from within the `handle_read`.